# Что говорится в ошибке? И как её исправить?

Tags: android, json

Имеется LoginActivity вот с таким кодом

```
public class Login extends Activity {

public static String URL_LOGIN = "http://mysite.ru/login";

EditText etLogin;
EditText etPassword;
Button btnLogin;
List<NameValuePair> params;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
ServerRequest serverRequest;
ProgressBar pbLogin;
Connection connection;


@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    serverRequest = new ServerRequest();

    pbLogin = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pbLogin);
    pbLogin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    etLogin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etLogin);
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);

    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            pbLogin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            String email = etLogin.getText().toString();
            String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
            params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            ServerRequest serverRequest = new ServerRequest();
            JSONObject json = serverRequest.getJSON(URL_LOGIN, params);
            if (json != null) {

                try {

                    String jsonstr = json.getString("response");
                    if (json.getBoolean("res")) {
                        String token = json.getString("token");
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                        editor.putString("token", token);
                        editor.apply();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Main.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }

                    Toast.makeText(getApplication(), jsonstr, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } catch (JSONException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }

        }

    });

}
```

И вот такой ServerRequest

```
public class ServerRequest {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";


public ServerRequest() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {


    try {

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line).append("n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
        Log.e("JSON", json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }


    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }


    return jObj;

}
JSONObject jobj;
public JSONObject getJSON(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

    Params param = new Params(url,params);
    Request myTask = new Request();
    try{
        jobj= myTask.execute(param).get();
    }catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return jobj;
}

private static class Params {
    String url;
    List<NameValuePair> params;


    Params(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {
        this.url = url;
        this.params = params;

    }
}

private class Request extends AsyncTask<Params, String, JSONObject> {

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(Params... args) {

        ServerRequest request = new ServerRequest();

        return request.getJSONFromUrl(args[0].url,args[0].params);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {

        super.onPostExecute(json);

    }

}
```

}

При подключении к серверу, сервер возвращает токен, это видно в Log-ах, но после этого начинают появляться ошибки.

```
     04-10 11:38:50.768 2656-2926/com.dpa7dujijiepgmail.app E/token: {"status":"OK","token":"5de99ea9a1bb550c02a8c2c74e79ac485707dce021cd2b021c8b4567"}n
04-10 11:38:50.768 2656-2656/com.dpa7dujijiepgmail.app W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for response
04-10 11:38:50.772 2656-2656/com.dpa7dujijiepgmail.app W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
04-10 11:38:50.772 2656-2656/com.dpa7dujijiepgmail.app W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:510)
04-10 11:38:50.772 2656-2656/com.dpa7dujijiepgmail.app W/System.err:     at com.dpa7dujijiepgmail.app.Login$1.onClick(Login.java:67)
04-10 11:38:50.772 2656-2656/com.dpa7dujijiepgmail.app W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
04-10 11:38:50.772 2656-2656/com.dpa7dujijiepgmail.app W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
04-10 11:38:50.772 2656-2656/com.dpa7dujijiepgmail.app W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-10 11:38:50.772 2656-2656/com.dpa7dujijiepgmail.app W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-10 11:38:50.772 2656-2656/com.dpa7dujijiepgmail.app W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-10 11:38:50.772 2656-2656/com.dpa7dujijiepgmail.app W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
04-10 11:38:50.772 2656-2656/com.dpa7dujijiepgmail.app W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-10 11:38:50.772 2656-2656/com.dpa7dujijiepgmail.app W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-10 11:38:50.772 2656-2656/com.dpa7dujijiepgmail.app W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
04-10 11:38:50.772 2656-2656/com.dpa7dujijiepgmail.app W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-10 11:38:50.772 2656-2656/com.dpa7dujijiepgmail.app W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Я не могу разобраться в этой проблеме, что здесь не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по всему вы ожидаете json такого формата

```
{"status":"OK","token":"5de99ea9a1bb550c02a8c2c74e79ac485707dce021cd2b021c8b4567"}
```

а в коде вы пытаетесь сделать так

```
 String jsonstr = json.getString("response");
```

в вашем json нет ключа "response" вот и логи в консоле из-за этого, аналогичная ситуация будет для

```
json.getBoolean("res")
```

Вам сначала нужно убедится, а есть ли в json такой ключ

```
if (jsonObject.has("response")) {
    //тогда получаем значение по этому ключу
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В дополнение ответа Yury Pashkov.

Проверить есть ли такой ключ в полученном JSON можно так же с помощью метода `jsonResponse.optString("//Ваш ключ")`.

Для примера, проверка в данном случае выглядела бы так:

```
    String jsonstr = json.optString("response"); //Вернет либо пустую строку  
                                                 //либо значение по ключу если оно есть.

    if (!jsonstr.equals("")) {

       //Ваш код если значение по данному ключу есть в JSON.

    } else {

        //Ваш код если значение по данному ключу в JSON отсутствует.

    }
```